# UnitTest - Check the behavior or the result of a method?

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm new to UnitTests and sometimes unsure what  my UnitTest
should test.

The following is a very simplified example

```
class MappingHelper
{
   private $mappingRepository;
   public function __construct(MappingRepository $mappingRepository)
   {
      $this->$mappingRepository = $mappingRepository
   }

  public function getMappingForCode(string $code)
  {
     return $this->mappingRepository->getMappingForCode($code);
  } 
}
```

So this is basicly only a wrapper method.
Should I check the behavior, or the result of the method?

**Result**
That would be more effort and somehow also redundant because I already 
test the functionality in the UnitTest for MappingRepository itself.

**Behavior**
It seems more useful to me only to check if the method 'getValueForCode' of
$this->mappingRepository was called once with parameter $code.

A problem with this solution is that the dependency is final and has no interface, 
so I can't mock it and therefore don't have the chance to check if the method was called.

Of course I could remove the final, but I don't want the class to be extended.
Also an interface is not necessary because there will be no other implementation.

So I would make this change only to be able to create the UnitTest, that doesn't feel right somehow.

Comment: Ask yourself what you want to test. You can test if the components work nicely together by mocking the repo and check if the helper calls the `getMappingForCode` method. The workings of the repo are in the repo test.

Comment: I want to make sure that the method returns the result I expected, which methods are called internally is irrelevant to me. Of course I have to call and "configure" the methods anyway, whether mock or real instance. But if I do this I test the code twice, maybe it's just fine.

Comment: Make it an integration test then, no mocking. You put A in and should get B back.

Comment: Okay, so in this example no UnitTest for this helper/method at all?

Comment: You can use phpunit for it, no problem. Just put the integration tests into a separate folder. In the test create the `MappingHelper` object and use it, put the output in a variable and assert it. When the scope of the integration goes over multiple application then you need another tool. But you want to test the integration of small parts.